# Can NodeMCU receive grayscale image files from a server over HTTP?

Tags: http, servlets, nodemcu

I want to send a grayscale image file from server to NodeMCU as a response to an HTTP request. Does anyone has any idea about how to achieve the same?

Comment: By "NodeMCU" you mean the Lua firmware, not the NodeMCU devkit and e.g. Arduino, right?

Comment: I mean the board with the inbuilt wifi module.

Comment: Then it's important to understand what kind of firmware you use on the devkit: Arduino, Espressif SDK, AT firmware, Lua, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You send

```
GET /abc123.jpg HTTP/1.1
Host: yourdomain.com
```

using a TCP connection. And then you listen for the response which will be something like this:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: image/jpeg
Content-Length: 1024

1024 BYTES OF BINARY DATA REPRESENTING THE IMAGE
```

So you just have to parse the response in a way that you can save the binary data (which is your image).